# How to edit a final object in a stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page in my app (stateful widget) that has a few fields and creates an object (`Contract`). I would like to use this same page to allow the user to edit the same object.

The logic I am trying to implement is if a object is passed to the page, then use that, otherwise make a new object. The issue is that the object must be `final`, and therefor I cannot change it after `null` is passed to it (meaning this should be a new object).

It seems very redundant if I have to have two pages which are mostly identical (one to edit, and one to create).

Current code:

```dart
class ContractEditPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Contract contract;

  ContractEditPage({Key key, this.contract}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ContractEditPageState createState() => _ContractEditPageState();
}

class _ContractEditPageState extends State<ContractEditPage> {
  bool editMode = false;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Check it editting contract
    if (widget.contract != null) editMode = true;

    // Generate Default Reminders
    if (!editMode) {
        //Create a new contract
        widget.contract = Contract(); // <= This is not allowed since contract is final
    else
    {
        //Use existing contract for field values
    }
}

... // Build method below
```

Comment: One workaround (and possibly best solution) I thought of - pass a new contract object to the page if it should be a new one, otherwise pass the existing object. The logic just happens before getting to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several alternatives to solve your problem one of them, without changing much your current logic would be the following:

```
class ContractEditPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Contract contract;

  ContractEditPage({Key key, this.contract}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ContractEditPageState createState() => _ContractEditPageState();
}

class _ContractEditPageState extends State<ContractEditPage> {
  bool editMode = false;
  Contract _contract; // ---------->  Add this

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _contract = widget.contract;

    // Check it editing contract
    if (_contract != null) editMode = true;

    // Generate Default Reminders
    if (!editMode) {
        //Create a new contract
       _contract = Contract(); // ---------->  Here is the change
    else
    {
        //Use existing contract for field values
    }
}
```